# Cannot Make Login Work in Smack and Openfire

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have been following this tutorial I found on GitHub to try and make a connection to an OpenFire server. I have used spark before and am now trying to use Smack api to create a simple android app to use on the go. I have followed a few tutorials and eventually stumbled upon this from Github:
https://github.com/axcl/SMACK-API-Android-Demo

**The problem is when I click the login button, I do not see my presence online in the OpenFire administrator panel.**

Here is the code:
**Myxmpp.java**

```
public class Myxmpp {
private static final String DOMAIN = "192.168.2.14";
private static final String HOST = "192.168.2.14";
private static final int PORT = 5222;
private String userName ="";
private String passWord = "";
AbstractXMPPConnection connection ;
ChatManager chatmanager ;
Chat newChat;
XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
private boolean connected;
private boolean isToasted;
private boolean chat_created;
private boolean loggedin;


//Initialize
public void init(String userId,String pwd ) {
    Log.i("XMPP", "Initializing!");
    this.userName = userId;
    this.passWord = pwd;
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
    configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
    configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    configBuilder.setResource("Android");
    configBuilder.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
    configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
    configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
    //configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
    connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

}

// Disconnect Function
public void disconnectConnection(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void connectConnection()
{
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            // Create a connection
            try {
                connection.connect();
                login();
                connected = true;

            } catch (IOException e) {
            } catch (SmackException e) {

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
            }

            return null;
        }
    };
    connectionThread.execute();
}


public void sendMsg() {
    if (connection.isConnected()== true) {
        // Assume we've created an XMPPConnection name "connection"._
        chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        newChat = chatmanager.createChat("concurer@nimbuzz.com");

        try {
            newChat.sendMessage("Howdy!");
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void login() {

    try {
        connection.login(userName, passWord);
        //Log.i("LOGIN", "Yey! We're connected to the Xmpp server!");

    } catch (XMPPException | SmackException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}



//Connection Listener to check connection state
public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {
    @Override
    public void connected(final XMPPConnection connection) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Connected!");
        connected = true;
        if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {
            login();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosed() {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionCLosed!");
        connected = false;
        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ConnectionClosedOn Error!");
        connected = false;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {

        Log.d("xmpp", "Reconnectingin " + arg0);

        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {



                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionFailed!");
        connected = false;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });
        Log.d("xmpp", "ReconnectionSuccessful");
        connected = true;

        chat_created = false;
        loggedin = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
        Log.d("xmpp", "Authenticated!");
        loggedin = true;

        chat_created = false;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
        if (isToasted)

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });
    }
}
```

}

**ConnectXmpp.java**

```
public class ConnectXmpp extends Service {

    private String userName;
    private String passWord;
    private Myxmpp xmpp = new Myxmpp();

    public ConnectXmpp() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        return new Localbinder<ConnectXmpp>(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        if(intent != null){
            userName = intent.getStringExtra("user");
            passWord = intent.getStringExtra("pwd");
            xmpp.init(userName, passWord);
            xmpp.connectConnection();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        xmpp.disconnectConnection();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ConnectXmpp mService;
    private View view;
    private boolean mBounded;
    private final ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(final ComponentName name,
                                       final IBinder service) {
            mService = ((Localbinder<ConnectXmpp>) service).getService();
            mBounded = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(final ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
            mBounded = false;
            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Click Handler for Login Button
    public void onClickLoginBtn(View view)
    {
        try {
            EditText userId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
            EditText userPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            String userName = userId.getText().toString();
            String passWord = userPwd.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ConnectXmpp.class );
            intent.putExtra("user",userName);
            intent.putExtra("pwd",passWord);
            startService(intent);



            //mService.connectConnection(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




}
```

I know this is a lot but I am really confused with this whole XMPP stuff. Any help on how to connect an already registered user would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

hi i have checked your code and  are you sure your domain name and host name is same. According to your issue, you are not able to login with xmpp using app.

Try this github example.This made my me.So if you got any issue i can help you.

https://github.com/saveendhiman/XMPPSample_Studio

Thank you hope this will help you.